# Perform nested sort without inner_hits in ElasticSearch

Tags: sorting, elasticsearch, nested, tire, elasticsearch-dsl

I need some help on querying records from **ELasticSearch (1.7.3)**. We will be getting a list of  evaluations performed and display only the last  evaluation done as shown below:

```
 evaluation: [
  {
    id: 2,
    breaches: null
  },
  {
    id: 6,
    breaches: null
  },
  {
    id: 7,
    breaches: null
  },
  {
    id: 15,
    breaches: null
  },
  {
    id: 18,
    breaches: [
      "rule_one",
      "rule_two",
      "rule_three"
    ]
  },
  {
    id: 19,
    breaches: [
      "rule_one",
      "rule_two",
      "rule_three"
    ]
  }
]
```

Now we need to query records on the basis of latest evaluation performed, that is to query only on the last object of the evaluation array. We found out the there is a support of inner_hits to sort and limit the nested records. For that we wrote a query to sort on the basis of  `evaluation id` in desc order and limit its size to 1 as shown below:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": {
        "nested": {
          "path": " evaluation",
          "query": {
            "bool": {
              "must": {
                "term": {
                  " evaluation. breaches": "rule_one"
                }
              }
            }
          },
          "inner_hits": {
            "sort": {
              " evaluation.id": {
                "order": "desc"
              }
            },
            "size": 1
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Please find the mapping below:

```
evaluation: {
  type: "nested",
  properties: {
    id: {
      type: "long"
    },
    breaches: {
      type: "string"
    }
  }
}
```

We tried sorting records but it did not worked, can you suggest some other ways to search on just the last object of nested records.

Thanks.

Comment: if you can't find inner_hits working in ES 1.0.12 then you can upgrade your ES to latest stable.

Comment: i have upgraded to 1.7.3 , which supports inner_hits, but it is still not working. It is returning the doc if it matches breaches in any of the nested objects instead of just the last object.

Comment: yeah, that will be a little tricky, have to take a look , can you share your mappings and settings

Comment: Here is the mapping: 
evaluation: {
  type: "nested",
  properties: {
    id: {
      type: "long"
    },
    breaches: {
      type: "string"
    }
  }
}

Comment: Settings: 

settings: {
index: {
creation_date: "1489476307113",
uuid: "q4c7BPDCSsiiP10kSlEfBg",
number_of_replicas: "1",
analysis: {
analyzer: {
reverse_analyzer: {
type: "custom",
filter: [
"standard",
"reverse"
],
tokenizer: "keyword"
}
}
},
number_of_shards: "5",
version: {
created: "1070399"
}
}
}

Comment: any one ???????

Comment: Did you ever find out what was wrong? Because your syntax seems right.

Comment: Yeah the syntax was right but I don't remember specifically how it worked.